# Changing device orientation settings by Device in Rubymotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have an universal app using Rubymotion, and the UI setup differs greatly between iPhone version and iPad version.

The main being, in iPhone it only supports portrait, and iPad only supports landscape.

I want to do this, if possible by setting something up on the Rakefile, from what I understand the alternative would be to do something in the delagate method, but if it where possible I would like to set orientation settings in the settings file.

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  #app settings
  app.name = 'xxxxx'
  app.version = "0.xxxx"
  app.device_family = [:iphone, :ipad]
  app.interface_orientations = [:portrait]
end
```

EDIT:

some updates on how Jamon's answer worked out.
having shouldAutorotate return false in the UINavigation resulted in odd occurrences on the iPad version,  having parts of the iPad version show its view content as portrait even though the orientation is set to landscape, it worked out when I returned true for shouldAutorotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do that in your Rakefile, as far as I know. You need to specify that you provide both orientations and then programmatically tell iOS whether an orientation is supported or not.

Your UIViewControllers and/or UINavigationController(s) should look like this:

```
def ipad?
  NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary["UIDeviceFamily"].include?("2")
end

def shouldAutorotate
  false # I think?
end

def supportedInterfaceOrientations
  if ipad?
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight
  else
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
  end      
end

def preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
  ipad? ? UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft : UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
end
```

Haven't tested this code, but I've used similar in the past. You can use ternary (like I did in the last method) or a regular `if`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I had to go that way. Things are so different from Rails. so much to learn.

Comment: Got it working, I was using UINavigationController so I had to subclass it and call shouldAutorotate in there, but that was about it with problems, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight, is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

as of today, the following works.

app_delegate.rb :

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window                       = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    @window.rootViewController    = AppController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end
```

AppController.rb (or whatever name you'd want to give to it) :

```
class AppController < UIViewController

  def viewDidLoad
    view.backgroundColor   =  UIColor.blackColor
    @label                 = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame( CGRectMake(100,100,200,50) )
    @label.textColor       = UIColor.whiteColor
    @label.text            = "Handling device orientation"
    view.addSubview(@label)
  end


  def ipad?
    return true if UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
  end

  def shouldAutorotate
    false
  end

  def supportedInterfaceOrientations
    if ipad?
      UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight
    else
      UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
    end      
  end

  def preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    ipad? ? UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft : UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
  end


end
```

The added label in AppController just gives a visual hint about it.